# How to link username in site to PayPal information email?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, paypal-subscriptions

It's not a problem but i don't know how to do this; let's say that I have a sign up form with some fields: **username, password, email,** as you know the user clicks on the BUY BUTTON and pay's up.

Well, how can I know the username that just made the payment, I mean how can I link those two things together, one idea it's to use the email address, but mose of the people sign up with different email addresses, mabe they have a different paypal address...you know...I need this information because I need a way to activate the account.

And I also need to know, if the user canceled a subscription will paypal post a message to my IPN link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the following PHP script for easy integration with PayPal's service (assuming you're using PHP): http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html

If you do, the e-mail you will be looking for will be supplied in

```
$paypal->ipn_data['payer_email']
```

(again, assuming that `$paypal` is your object of the paypal_class class)

Obviously you have to follow the setup steps first. I suggest using the example script. It is really easy to do - in only four steps.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read the official paypal documentation about IPN and recurring payments.

PayPal issues a IPN for every event that occurs to the user subscription, for example:

subscr_signup
subscr_eot
subscr_cancel
subscr_failed

About the parameter, you can use a parameter named "custom" to pass a value, for example the user id or email, and that parameter will be sent you in every IPN.

Answer (score 1):

Here are implementations of the PayPal IPN in both C# and VB:

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/PPIPNDesc.aspx

Here's an account of how I incorporated it into a PayPal subscriptions scenario:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/07/10/ASPNET-PayPal-Subscriptions-IPN.aspx